# How can I require a QA or manual tester for a PR in GitHub?

Tags: github

When somebody creates a PR (Pull Request) in GitHub, I'd like to require the following things before they can merge to master:

1. A senior developer reviews the code
2. A CICD system builds the code and tests pass
3. A manual tester / QA person reviews the deployed system from #2

1 and 2 are pretty easy. How do I do #3?  I tried to make it so that 2 reviewers were required, but it seems those reviewers need to have *write/admin* access to the code, which is really not what I'm looking for.

How can I make it so somebody from a QA group has to review the user's work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom GitHub action like [required-review](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/required-review) or [required-reviews](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/required-reviews), which allows you to require at least one review from different groups of users.